# Can't draw in UITableViewCell's drawRect

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-graphics

I'm having trouble drawing in the drawRect method of my custom UITableViewCell. Here is the code I am using

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef ctx  = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGPoint origin    = _faceView.frame.origin;
    CGFloat width     = _faceView.frame.size.width;
    CGFloat height    = _faceView.frame.size.height;
    CGFloat border    = 2.0f;


    CGPoint startPt   = CGPointMake(origin.x + width/2, self.frame.size.height);
    CGContextBeginPath(ctx);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, startPt.x, startPt.y);

    CGPoint basePt    = CGPointMake(startPt.x, origin.y - height - border);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, basePt.x, basePt.y);

    CGRect circleRect = CGRectMake(origin.x - border, origin.y - border, width + 2 * border, height + 2 * border);
    CGContextAddEllipseInRect(ctx, circleRect);

    UIColor *color = [UIColor redColor];
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, color.CGColor);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(ctx, color.CGColor);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 1.0f);

    CGContextDrawPath(ctx, kCGPathFillStroke);
}
```

I've debugged to make sure that all of the numeric values make sense and it appears that they do. Can't really find out why nothing is being drawn on screen.

For what its worth, this is a cell defined in a nib as well. And i'm building with the iOS 7 sdk.

Any ideas?

tahnks

Comment: I agree. Do your best not to use drawRect method unless needed because  it affects the performance of how things run.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You probably shouldn't do this in UITableViewCell's own drawRect. Instead, create a custom UIView and add it as a subview.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527925/subclassed-uitableviewcell-backgroundview-covers-up-anything-i-do-in-drawrect).

Answer (score 15):

Try set backgroungcolor property to transparent color

```
self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to set

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
       .....
       [cell setNeedsDisplay];
       return cell;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try set `backgroundColor` of `contentView` property to clear color

```
self.contentView = [UIColor clearColor];
```