# UITableViewCell custom CG drawing iOS 7

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-graphics, ios7

I have a `UITableViewCell` subclass with the following `drawRect:` implementation. It will draw a line at the bottom of the cell, indented by 30 points to match our design. The `tableView.separatorStyle` is set to `UITableViewSeparatorStyleNone` in lieu of this custom drawing.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [super drawRect:rect];

    if (!_hideBottomLine) {
        CGContextRef ref = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        CGContextSetShouldAntialias(ref, NO);

        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(ref, [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.75 alpha:1].CGColor);
        CGContextSetLineWidth(ref, 1);
        CGContextMoveToPoint(ref, 30, CGRectGetMaxY(rect));
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(ref, CGRectGetMaxX(rect), CGRectGetMaxY(rect));
        CGContextStrokePath(ref);
    }
}
```

This worked great in iOS 6 and on iOS 7 when built with the iOS 6 SDK. Now that I am building with the iOS 7 SDK the line does not appear.

Am I missing some change with CG drawing in the iOS 7 SDK?

**EDIT:**

So I now realize there is a better way to do this in iOS 7 using `cell.separatorInset`, I also found some other similar CG code I had written that works. So I think the issue is isolated to implementing `drawRect:` on `UITableViewCell`

I'd still like an answer on how to do custom drawing on the cell in iOS 7 though.

Comment: Are those lines within the cell limit? iOS7 has a new subview that clips to bounds anything you add to the contentView.

Comment: These specifically are on the edge, so it's possible they're getting clipped as you say. However, I use the same technique in another cell where I draw a vertical line in the center of the cell which is not displaying in iOS 7.

Comment: Just try to remove the hidden clipping mechanism in iOS7 and see what happens:

[cell.contentView.superview setClipsToBounds:NO];

Answer (score 3):

Try set background color property to transparent color

```
self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]
```

Comment: So strange. This made the drawing appear in the cell. May you kindly explain why?

Comment: I think, custom draw make image in background view, but cell have content view and if you not set clear color, content view will be showing under your custom background

Comment: In iOS 7 the default background view is white. Before it was clearColor.

Answer (score 2):

You must create subview with drawRect and put it to your UITableViewCell

look here [Can't draw in UITableViewCell's drawRect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18883975/cant-draw-in-uitableviewcells-drawrect)