# UIRectFill is not working in iOS 7

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios6, ios7

**Trying to draw a rect in UITableViewCell**

```
//Works with iOS6 and earlier but NOT with ( iOS7 )

 - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    // Creating a black border
    [[UIColor blackColor] setFill];
    UIRectFill(CGRectMake(10, 5, 40, 43));

    // Filling with rig color
    [[UIColor colorWithRed:r green:g blue:b alpha:a] setFill];
    UIRectFill(CGRectMake(11, 6, 38, 41));
}
```

Does anybody know why this doesn't work in iOS 7 but does in iOS 6?

Comment: Erm...some more information about why it is not working would be helpful.

Comment: That is what, I am trying to figure out why the hell is not working with iOS7. Could you please check this method with your any UItableViewCell class ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue under iOS 7 - anything you draw in your `-drawRect` method gets obscured by the cell's subviews. Instead, add an instance of a new view subclass as a subview to your cells `contentView` and do the drawing there.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18883975/cant-draw-in-uitableviewcells-drawrect) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527925/subclassed-uitableviewcell-backgroundview-covers-up-anything-i-do-in-drawrect). If you don't want to crate a custom subclass, you could use [block drawing views](https://github.com/hsjunnesson/UIViewDrawRectBlock) instead.

Comment: Thanks MrMage for giving me hint.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it by adding a subview to contentview

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style 
                              reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier{
      if(!self)
         return self;

      self.colorView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 5, 40, 43)];
      self.colorView.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
      self.colorView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
      [self.contentView addSubview:self.colorView];

  }

- (void)setActivityColor:(UIColor*)color
{
    [self.colorView setBackgroundColor:color];
}
```