# CoreGraphics not working on iOS 7.0 simulator

Tags: ios, core-graphics, ios7

I've been struggling with this since the iOS 7 alpha. First I thought it was a bug on the alpha, but it's still happening, so I'm doing something wrong.

All around the app I'm drawing stuff like cell backgrounds, and such with CG, but in iOS 7 it's not displayed.

as an example:

```
@interface NewManagerCell : UITableViewCell
@end

@implementation NewManagerCell

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        //some initialization code here
    }
    return self;
}
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGRect bounds = self.bounds;
    bounds.origin.y += 5; //inter-cell spacing
    bounds.size.height -= 5;

    CGFloat mx = CGRectGetMinX(bounds);
    CGFloat Mx = CGRectGetMaxX(bounds);
    CGFloat my = CGRectGetMinY(bounds);
    CGFloat cy = CGRectGetMinY(bounds)+CGRectGetHeight(bounds)*.375;
    CGFloat My = CGRectGetMaxY(bounds);

    CGContextBeginPath(context);

    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, mx, cy);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, mx+cy-my, my);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, Mx-cy+my, my);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, Mx, cy);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, Mx, My);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, mx, My);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, mx, cy);

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cell-pattern"]] CGColor]);
    CGContextFillPath(context);

    mx += 4+CGRectGetWidth(bounds)/4-CGRectGetHeight(bounds)*.375/16;
    Mx -= 4;
    my += 4;
    My -= 4;
    cy += 2;

    CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();

    CGContextBeginPath(context);

    CGPathMoveToPoint(path, &CGAffineTransformIdentity, mx, my);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, &CGAffineTransformIdentity, Mx-(cy-my), my);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, &CGAffineTransformIdentity, Mx, cy);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, &CGAffineTransformIdentity, Mx, My);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, &CGAffineTransformIdentity, mx, My);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, &CGAffineTransformIdentity, mx, my);

    CGContextAddPath(context, path);
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1, 1, 1, 1);
    CGContextFillPath(context);

    CGContextAddPath(context, path);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, .69, .69, .69, 1);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);

    CGPathRelease(path);
}
@end
```

That worked in any flavor of iOS prior to 7 and now stopped working. Does anybody have any clue about what's happening?

Comment: possible duplicate of [subclassed UITableViewCell - backgroundView covers up anything I do in drawRect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527925/subclassed-uitableviewcell-backgroundview-covers-up-anything-i-do-in-drawrect)

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a custom `UIView` that contains the code to draw, and then you can addSubView that into your cell's root view.

Comment: I had the same problem last week and came up with an identical solution :-) You can use something like https://github.com/hsjunnesson/UIViewDrawRectBlock to avoid subclassing.

Comment: That's a clever idea!

Comment: If this answers your question, please mark this as the answer. Thanks :)