# UITableViewCell backgroundView draw rect not being called

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I'm having a heck of a time getting a cell's `backgroundView` to display.

The code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // assume cell is dequeued correctly (i.e. cell != nil)

    UIView *backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame];
    backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    cell.backgroundView = backgroundView;
    [cell.backgroundView setNeedsDisplay];

    return cell;
}
```

I also tried this in `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`. Still no luck.

I attempted subclassing the `UIView` object used as the backgroundView and confirmed `drawRect` is never being called.

Answer (score 1):

You probably shouldn't do this in the UITableViewCell's own drawRect. Instead, create a custom UIView and add it as a subview.

See also this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527925/subclassed-uitableviewcell-backgroundview-covers-up-anything-i-do-in-drawrect)

If all that youre doing is trying to set the color of the tableView's cell then simply set the cell's.ContentView to the desired color.

Comment: I did not override `UITableViewCell`'s `drawRect` as per my last sentence.  I tested with a subclassed `UIView` object to use as the backgroundView.  `drawRect` was never called for that custom view.  I'm not messing with the cell's internals.  The backgroundView is simply not showing up and I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working for me (I get a bunch of  yellow cells) but only if I'm returning numberOfRowsInSection: You sure that is working? Otherwise I get the empty white cells since I told the TableView there is nothing to show.

For example

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 10;
}
```